# Hot to change 'Preemptibilty' setting on VM instance in Google Cloud

Tags: configuration, google-cloud-platform

Currently running a small number of machines in Google Cloud Platform.  When originally setup, the 'Preemptibility' availability policy was turned on and the machine is being terminated by Google.

Looking for a way to the Google 'Preemptibility' policy off so the machines stay powered on at all times without having to build new machines.

GUI does not appear to have an option to turn off and unable to find a command line option either.

Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, we don't have a crystal ball, and are not able to make a guess at what virtualization system you're using. Please edit your question with more details on your environment, including what you've tried, and what documentation you've read on the topic.

Comment: My apologies.  Since this was listed on Google Cloud and a resource, i wrongly assumed that this was specifically about the Google cloud.

Answer (score 4):

You most likely can't. This is equivalent to the AWS Spot instance, and the instances billing function is set at startup and is immutable. https://cloud.google.com/preemptible-vms/ states "Preemptible VMs offer the same machine types and options as regular compute instances and last for up to 24 hours.", so you are going to have to recreate that functionality on a standard node.

Comment: how do you destroy a cluster and recreate it?